# Calling a method with arguments after certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to call a method after certain time.
This is just an example.

```
 - (void)myMethod:(int)value1 setValue2:(CGPoint)value2{

 //Do Something with values


}
```

At first I thought

```
   [self scheduleOnce:@selector(myMethod:setValue2:) delay:timeToWait];
```

but I can't pass the arguments when using selector, so Im asking you guys for an alternative...What could I do?
Thanks for your time guys and have a great day!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not C#.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Totally agree with you, I didn't notice that was the tag I had added. Honest mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `GCD`'s `dispatch_after`. For instance:

```
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self myMethod:someValue setValue2: someValue2];
    });
```

Comment: @user1876553 Another option is to use an `NSTimer` but using `dispatch_after` is a much better solution.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried dispatch_after but for some reason the whole program stopped. I used '1' instead of 'delayInSeconds'. Do I need to #define something? :/ I added a log to see if something is happening, it Ain't....

Comment: Replacing `delayInSeconds` with `1` is fine. The code should work. When you say the whole program stopped, what do you mean? Did the app crash or is the UI hung? Perhaps you ended up with a deadlock or infinite loop. Tap the pause icon in the debugger and see what is going on when it appears stopped.

Comment: @rmaddy yup, it was an infinite loop, I didn't notice I was trying to make a quick check on your solution(which worked like a charm) inside a while-loop. Thanks Rmdady. You're going to heaven.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your arguments into an `NSDictionary` and pass that as the object parameter to `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`

Comment: +1 for not using GCD; I just can't stand that weird blocks syntax.

Comment: @herzbube Learn to embrace blocks. It solves so many problems and makes so many things easier. Having to create a whole new method and package (then unpack) a dictionary of parameter values is just so much more work than making a simple call to a block. Cramming a whole set of arguments into a dictionary eliminates the ability of the compiler to do any type checking and it requires the overhead of wrapping native types like `int` or `float`. Granted block syntax takes some time to learn but compare it to all of the overhead code you need to write to call `performSelector:`.

Comment: @rmaddy Generally speaking, I prefer clarity over brevity and performance. I want to be able to read my code in 2 years time without having to puzzle over my own cleverness at the time I originally wrote that stuff. For that sake I _am_ indeed willing to write a certain amount of overhead code. That being said, I of course agree with you that blocks should be used after a certain limit of overhead has been reached.

Comment: @herzbube I agree that readability and maintainability are the most important factors. Just remember that blocks are getting used more and more in the Cocoa/Cocoa Touch APIs. Enjoy.